# What is identityservicesd?

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, keychain

*Just a preface I do not have anything noticeably wrong with my computer (MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), Mojave 10.14.4), and I was learning as I went along.

In the process of cleaning out my computer I noticed a key in my login keychain just named `<key>`.

[image: Who dis?]
[image: identityservicesd.app]

The only information listed is `identityservicesd.app`

What can be found on Google, StackExchange, StackOverflow, Apple Support Forums, Reddit and blogs about `identityserviced`:

1. Macinside.info - `identityservicesd` is a background process (Identity Services Daemon) that deals with third-party credentials.
2. People complaining of bugging, performance issues, login errors, repetitive prompts requesting system access, security concerns.
3. Recommending solutions to fix these problems (if you have these problems, more or less everyone is recommended to follow these [steps](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7432487#29671481022))
4. No other information about the process.

My questions are:

- What is `identityservicesd`?
- Why is it that it's credentials in my keychain just named `<key>`?

Even if this is a background benign process, it does seem to act in a strange way when it does have to interact with the user. This can be very concerning or confusing for someone not knowledgeable (me). Since information on this is pretty limited, at the least I hope to clarify the strange behavior I described.

---

I would like to also list the process I used when searching my system as I think someone inexperienced like myself would probably search everywhere, and cobble together something similar. Hopefully this will either save you from wasting time or at the least help.

### Where is this on my mac?

Using `sudo find / -iname "*identityservicesd*"`

```
/System/Library/Sandbox/Profiles/com.apple.identityservicesd.sb    
/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.identityservicesd.plist 
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/MacOS/identityservicesd
/private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.identityservicesd.plist
/private/var/folders/cy/[hash#]/T/com.apple.identityservicesd
/private/var/folders/cy/[hash#]/C/com.apple.identityservicesd
~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.identityservicesd.[hash#].plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.identityservicesd.plist
```

**Note: [hash#] self inputed. Also I had success earlier getting past the `operation not permitted` error by changing [privacy permissions](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/), but the error returned again and now can't access it.**

`sudo locate -i "*identityservicesd*"` worked predictably. Only searching within system files, but going deeper into the files.

```
/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.identityservicesd.plist
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Info.plist
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/MacOS
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/MacOS/identityservicesd
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/PkgInfo
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/FaceTime.icns
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/IDS.icns
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ar.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ar.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ar.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ca.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ca.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ca.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/com.apple.private.alloy.digitalhealth.plist
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/com.apple.private.alloy.facetime.lp.plist
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/cs.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/cs.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/cs.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/da.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/da.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/da.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/el.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/el.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/el.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/en_AU.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/en_AU.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/en_AU.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/en_GB.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/en_GB.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/en_GB.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/es.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/es.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/es.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/es_419.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/es_419.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/es_419.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/fi.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/fi.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/fi.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/fr.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/fr.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/fr.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/fr_CA.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/fr_CA.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/fr_CA.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/he.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/he.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/he.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/hi.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/hi.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/hi.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/hr.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/hr.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/hr.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/hu.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/hu.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/hu.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/iCloud.icns
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/id.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/id.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/id.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/it.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/it.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/it.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ja.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ja.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ja.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ko.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ms.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ms.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ms.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/nl.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/nl.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/nl.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/no.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/no.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/no.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/pl.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/pl.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/pl.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/pt.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/pt.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/pt.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/pt_PT.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/pt_PT.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/pt_PT.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ro.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ro.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ro.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ru.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ru.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/ru.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/sk.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/sk.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/sk.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/sv.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/sv.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/sv.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/th.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/th.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/th.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/tr.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/tr.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/tr.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/uk.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/uk.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/uk.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/vi.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/vi.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/vi.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/zh_CN.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/zh_HK.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/zh_HK.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/zh_HK.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/IDSLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources/zh_TW.lproj/IdentityServicesLocalizable.strings
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/_CodeSignature
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/version.plist
/System/Library/Sandbox/Profiles/com.apple.identityservicesd.sb
```

Everything looks fine.

Broadening the search to "identityservices", `find` catches both "identityservices" and "identityservicesd" files from `~/Library`

`sudo mdfind -onlyin ~/Library "identityservices"` found 0 files in `~/Library`.

Both commands search differently of course.

What started this whole hunt was that `mdfind` was able to find other file name searches in `~/Library`, but `~/Library/IdentityServices` was not found when searched for. At the start I thought this was something malicious, but I'm thinking it might just be unlisted.

### Certificates

`codesign --display --verbose=4 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app`

```
Executable=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/MacOS/identityservicesd
Identifier=com.apple.identityservicesd
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=60332 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1878+5 location=embedded
Platform identifier=7
VersionPlatform=1
VersionMin=658944
VersionSDK=658944
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256= <hash>
Hash choices=sha256
Page size=4096
CDHash= <hash>
Signature size=4485
Authority=Software Signing
Authority=Apple Code Signing Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Info.plist entries=31
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=84
Internal requirements count=1 size=76
```

What concerned me was 3 things: the TeamIdentifier was not set, the Authority, and when I couldn't get an output from `shasum -a 256 <file>`.

1. `openssl dgst -sha256 <file>` sorted out the hash check.
2. Still dont know why TeamIdentifier is not set
3. According to Apple's [TrustStore](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209144) "Apple Root CA" is trusted, however I cannot find mention of both "Apple Code Signing Certification Authority" or "Software Signing"

**Edit: after some more research I was able to I feel pretty confident that:**

**1. `identityservicesd` TeamIdentifier not being set is fine, after comparing it to terminal.app [Apple Dev Code Signing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html)**

**2. "Software Signing" also fine. [Software Signing](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2018/08/08/demystifying-ios-app-provisioning-process/)**

Comment: This reads like a very broad question. Is there a more narrow question twhihc someone might answer in a paragraph or two? If so please make an edit to the post to ask a specific question at the end so we might be able to help you at least get one step down the road to understanding what this system daemon does

Comment: The question is okay. Before answer is arrived, do not do the mistake and be sure macOS is fine with stuff included into it, be it keyboard driver or identityserviced. I have this <key> too.

Comment: @bmike I agree. My intention was to have one place that confirms both the identity of `identityservicesd` and why OSX Keychain Access simply shows <key> with no other information other than the app in question. Where I think I have become too broad is with my last question. Here I want to have the advice of knowledgable people posted in one place, for inexperienced people like myself to read, that covers  some methods to self research/diagnose concerns when reviewing keys and certificates. If this is still too broad or considered 2 posts, I will remove this question and post it separately.

Comment: @bmike Less broad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything you post seems on the up and up.

- official apple daemon that would be expected to encrypt data and routinely generate keys and store them in the keychain
- lots of matches for the framework on disk
- signed app that is valid
- well documented SDK and API - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/IdentityServices_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

It is a system daemon that helps manage personally identifying and/or items that could be tracked or compromise your privacy if they were just stored plainly on the filesystem in standard locations.

Comment: Very clear and succinct. I can see this clearing up most confusion, and also giving those with fresh eyes a good framework while reviewing questionable processes or files.

Comment: Any ideas why this process would need access to the internet though?

Comment: Key / certificate revocation lists and such are typically hosted externally from the OS @Lethargos

Answer (score 0):

### AirDrop -- which by itself works on LAN only -- nevertheless requires Internet access of `identityservicesd` via `IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent`

- For 2-3 years or longer I had the problem on macOS Big Sur that Airdrop was not working.
- My Mac (macOS 11.7.19 Big Sur) and iPhone (iOS 15.8) could always "see each other", so the discovery process worked.
- But as soon as I clicked send, the progress indicator went on, but spin indefinitely.

### Today I finally found the solution

- On my Mac, running LittleSnitch as my inbound/outbound firewall, I had a rule which had forbidden network access for `identityservicesd` via `IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent`. After deactivating this my errant manual rule Airdrop file exchange now works again.
- So interestingly even though the whole transfer happens in the LAN only, the setting `AirDrop: Contacts only` requires a roundtrip to the credential servers of apple.com. Strangely even with `AirDrop: Everyone` AirDrop does not work decentrally (as least in my circumstances). Probably this is a bug, or a certain circumstance, where there's a routine independent from the setting which nevertheless checks Apple servers, and if failing also fails the otherwise conceptually independent decentral setup "Airdrop: Everyone".

Comment: Sadly not reproducible. Not causally related.

Comment: Mac → iPhone always works (over all the years).

Comment: iPhone → Mac discovery/visibility always works. But sending mostly fails. My only successes were to first send a dummy file from the Mac to the iPhone. Then thereafter within a short "window of opportunity" (~ open session) send from the iPhone to the Mac. This sometimes works. I really have no idea what intervenes here.