# IdentityServices : "delete" folder containing 1 new file every 10 seconds

Tags: filesystem, macos

I have a problem with my `~/Library/IdentityServices/delete` folder.
It contained ~ a million files, that I'm trying to delete.

Now I'm realising that it is creating a new file, like, every 10 seconds.
10 last files for example:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:24 477D1790-07B2-49FD-BA29-96E44AA1CC63/
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:24 82FAE443-85DA-430D-BE5B-83A737DE2A84/
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:24 C4EBF7E3-B6E7-4265-9928-5D14AB8978E5/
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:24 96F36FD3-AE73-45CD-A1B2-C24F7065DA96/
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:25 E045DC82-EADD-47B4-A600-B1FF6D52F006/
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:25 3E63DE64-0AEE-4AAD-BD59-C54F210F713F/
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:25 FCA84FB9-CC05-44EF-999E-9E24DFD05B0E/
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:25 3CADC3AA-91DE-4B8D-ACE9-12607866472E/
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:25 C719E766-22DC-4FAE-AE9A-6B6FD25318A6/
drwxr-xr-x  2 theredled  staff    68B 30 déc 18:25 07DBF3E8-B23D-461C-A5A5-919C837D55F9/
```

I also have corresponding logs in `system.log` :

```
Dec 30 18:24:45 localhost-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.identityservicesd): Service only ran for 2 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 8 seconds.
Dec 30 18:24:51 localhost-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 30 18:24:54 localhost-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.identityservicesd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 30 18:25:02 localhost-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 30 18:25:04 localhost-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.identityservicesd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 30 18:25:12 localhost-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 30 18:25:15 localhost-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.identityservicesd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
^[[BDec 30 18:25:23 localhost-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

(don't know if `com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesd` is related)

I also have detail for each log line in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.
Here is a cropped example (`identityservicesd_2019-12-30-182700_localhost-2.crash`):

```
Process:               identityservicesd [1600]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/MacOS/identityservicesd
Identifier:            identityservicesd
Version:               10.0 (1000)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           identityservicesd [1600]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-12-30 18:26:59.438 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G2136)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        5AD9F50C-ECFA-9936-62F9-9B17A59970F6


Time Awake Since Boot: 1700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe16f00dc00'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9ea53b3b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffb3cdd1da objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9ead4514 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9e9c6703 ___forwarding___ + 1059
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9e9c6258 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   IDSFoundation                       0x00007fffad5d2baa IDSNetworkingLogDump + 48645
6   IDSFoundation                       0x00007fffad5ceef5 IDSNetworkingLogDump + 33104
7   identityservicesd                   0x0000000107740f4f identityservicesd + 2875215
8   identityservicesd                   0x000000010774142a identityservicesd + 2876458
9   identityservicesd                   0x00000001077412f7 identityservicesd + 2876151
10  identityservicesd                   0x0000000107740df3 identityservicesd + 2874867
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffb45db8fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffb45db8b9 dispatch_once_f + 38
13  identityservicesd                   0x0000000107740dad identityservicesd + 2874797
14  identityservicesd                   0x000000010757ba1a identityservicesd + 1018394
15  identityservicesd                   0x000000010757cfb3 identityservicesd + 1023923
16  identityservicesd                   0x0000000107568407 identityservicesd + 939015
17  identityservicesd                   0x0000000107567b79 identityservicesd + 936825
18  identityservicesd                   0x00000001074dc8c6 identityservicesd + 366790
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffb45e4524 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffb45db8fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fffb45e8aac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 925
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9ea09809 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9e9caabd __CFRunLoopRun + 2221
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9e9c9fb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
25  Foundation                          0x00007fffa03fdac2 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
26  Foundation                          0x00007fffa03fd99a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
27  identityservicesd                   0x00000001074d69cf identityservicesd + 342479
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffb4611235 start + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffb473fd42 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb482d457 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fffb46a5420 abort + 129
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fffb31ab94a abort_message + 266
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fffb31d0c2f default_terminate_handler() + 267
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fffb3cdf33e _objc_terminate() + 103
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fffb31cdd49 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fffb31cddc3 std::terminate() + 51
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb45db910 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb45db8b9 dispatch_once_f + 38
10  com.apple.identityservicesd     0x0000000107740dad 0x107483000 + 2874797
11  com.apple.identityservicesd     0x000000010757ba1a 0x107483000 + 1018394
12  com.apple.identityservicesd     0x000000010757cfb3 0x107483000 + 1023923
13  com.apple.identityservicesd     0x0000000107568407 0x107483000 + 939015
14  com.apple.identityservicesd     0x0000000107567b79 0x107483000 + 936825
15  com.apple.identityservicesd     0x00000001074dc8c6 0x107483000 + 366790
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb45e4524 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb45db8fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb45e8aac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 925
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9ea09809 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9e9caabd __CFRunLoopRun + 2221
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9e9c9fb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
22  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa03fdac2 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
23  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa03fd99a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
24  com.apple.identityservicesd     0x00000001074d69cf 0x107483000 + 342479
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffb4611235 start + 1


Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Any idea?

Version : MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: [What is identityservicesd?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356622/what-is-identityservicesd)

Comment: @ankii I know what it is (approximatively).

Comment: Note that it may be related to : https://superuser.com/questions/1156916/lots-of-mac-sierra-service-only-ran-for-0-seconds-log-errors (I also have seemingly related log lines in system.log)

Comment: Well, post your log too, then. Also macOS version. Did you try turning it off and on again ?

Comment: Done. Yes I tried to turn on and off without success - actually the problem seems to be there for months (having at least 500000 log lines).

Comment: Actually my calculations tell me it's here for a year (2,000,000 files with one every 10 seconds 16h/day). I know that comment is useless it's more of a reminder for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out upgrading to High Sierra made those logs and files disappear.