# Can I change port for identityserverd?

Tags: ventura

I have a program that needs port 7777 to function. Updating to Ventura broke it. Now I am getting

```
Ports are not available: listen udp 0.0.0.0:7777: bind: address already in use
```

Checking who uses port 7777:

```
$ lsof -i -P -n | grep 7777                                                                                                       
identitys  1471  ira   32u  IPv4 0xcea026c85ca11a61      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:7777

$ ps 1471                                                                                                                        
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
 1471   ??  S      0:00.89 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/MacOS/identityservicesd
```

This describes what identityservicesd.app is about: [What is identityservicesd?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356622/what-is-identityservicesd)

Killing it just causes it to restart. Disabling it probably isn't a good idea, it seems important. Can I change its port? How did it run prior to Ventura?

And, maybe because I am not familiar enough with UDP, how can it hog the port if its status isn't "LISTEN"?

Comment: Port 7777 is probably set in a plist file that is not user configurable. Is it possible to tell the program to bind to your Ethernet or Wi-Fi interface (for example `en0`) instead of to all of your interfaces (`0.0.0.0`)? `identityservicesd` binds to the loopback interface (`lo0`) only.

Comment: Is there a way to do that from command line?

Comment: Maybe. What program is it?

Comment: Something proprietary.

Comment: I can only guess, but some programs have configuration files or command-line arguments (running the program with `-h`, `-help` or `--help` may list them). If you can't change the port `identityservicesd` binds to, I'd recommend that you contact the program's developer.